# Three select-able lists vs drop down list + 2 lists

Tags: usability, interaction-design

I have a scenario where I can complete following 2 ways as below,

**1st way**

[image]

**2nd way**

[image]

Comment: Can multiple items be selected in the category box? (1st example)

Comment: @DarrylGodden nope

Comment: Voted up option 2 then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details: 2nd way.

Because you have two different interaction types.

- Selection of category
- Drag & drop between available & selected

You might also consider to add keyboard support (e.g. buttons to move items between the lists). How does the user know that items can be put in the second list? Is it obvious by the data?